# How to validate a field in Zod depending on the value of another field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, zod

I have a schema and I need to make it so that the **role** field is only validated when the value of the **subject** field is 1, otherwise the **role** should not be validated at all

```
const schema = z.object({
  subject: z.number().default(0),
  gender: z.object({
    owner: z.number(),
    stranger: z.number().array().min(1),
  }),
  age: z.object({
    owner: z.number(),
    stranger: z.number().array().min(1),
  }),
  role: z.object({
    owner: z.number(),
    stranger: z.number(),
  }),
});
```

I tried to use the refine method but it was unsuccessful. In all the code examples that I looked at, the refine only processed the field on which this method was called. In my case, I need to process another field

Comment: Please post your failing code with refine because this is the correct way to do it

Comment: Just `refine` the entire object?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to do it. The problem was that I was using **.refine** for the role field when I needed to use it for the schema as a whole

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle such conditional validation using `.refine(validator: (data:T)=>any, params?: RefineParams)` - [here](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#refine)

**Example implementation**:

```
const schema = z.object({
  subject: z.number().default(0),
  role: z.object({
    owner: z.number(),
    stranger: z.number(),
  }),
}).refine(data => data.subject !== 1 || (data.subject === 1 && data.role), {
  message: "Role field is required when subject equals 1",
  path: ['role'] // Pointing out which field is invalid
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! However, I had to add an **.optional()** to the role field because without it it still validated even if subject = 0